# Why do gram-negative bacteria attack the digestive system more than gram-positive ones?

Tags: bacteriology, digestive-system, infectious-diseases

I was researching for a biology project on the subject of contagious infections of the digestive system (mainly the intestines) and almost all of the bacteria that came up (E.coli, Shigella, Cholera, etc.) were gram-negative. Is there is reason that that type effects the digestive system so often or is it coincidental?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[Gastrointestinal](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/food-poisoning/symptoms-causes/syc-20356230) [infections](https://www.foodsafety.gov/food-poisoning/bacteria-and-viruses)** can be caused by Gram positive and negative bacteria:

**[Gram-positive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram-positive_bacteria):**

- *Staphylococcus aureus*
- *Clostridium difficile, botulinum* and *perfringens*
- *Listeria monocytogenes*
- *Bacillus cereus*

**[Gram-negative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram-negative_bacteria):**

- *Salmonella enteritidis* and *typhi*
- *Campylobacter jejuni*
- *Shigella*
- *Escherichia coli*
- *Vibrio cholerae* and *parahaemolyticus*
- *Helicobacter pylori*
- *Yersinia enterocolitica*

Any part of the GIT can be infected by G+ or G- bacteria:

- Stomach: *S. aureus* (G+), *H. pylori* (G-)
- Small intestine: *Bacillus cereus* (G+), *Salmonella enteritidis* (G-)
- Colon: *Clostridium difficile* (G+), *Shigella* (G-)

Certain bacteria typically affect only certain parts of GIT: *H. pylori* and *S. aureus* affect mainly the stomach; *C. difficile* affects mainly the colon.

Anyway, infections of the gastrointestinal tract are much more commonly caused by Gram negative than positive bacteria ([Stat Pearls, 2019](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK513295/)).

From the pathogenicity viewpoint, the main difference between Gram-positive and negative bacteria is that G+ bacteria produce exotoxins (which are proteins that bacteria secrete into their environment), while G- bacteria produce endotoxins (which are lipopolysaccharides as parts of bacterial walls). The differences between endo- and exotoxins ([microbiologyinfo.com](https://microbiologyinfo.com/differences-between-exotoxins-and-endotoxins/)):

- Endotoxins are heat stable, so they are not destroyed by cooking, they don't need specific receptors, they don't trigger antibodies and there are no vaccines against them.
- Exotoxins are heat unstable, they trigger antibody response and have specific receptors in the GIT.

---

More than 80% of **skin** infections is caused by **Gram positive** bacteria, such as *Staphylococci* and *Streptococci* ([Clinical Infectious Diseases](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6452002/)).

75-95% of uncomplicated **urinary** infections ([Microbiology Spectrum](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4888879/)) and most **sexually transmitted** infections ([Clinical Laboratory Science](http://clsjournal.ascls.org/content/30/2/114)) are caused by **Gram-negative** bacteria.

**Respiratory** infections are caused by **both** Gram-positive and negative bacteria ([Lumenlearning](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/microbiology/chapter/bacterial-infections-of-the-respiratory-tract/)).

So, the only pattern I see is that in dry/air-exposed areas (skin, respiratory tract), most infections are caused by Gram-positive bacteria, and in wet areas (gastrointestinal and genitourinary tract) by Gram-negative bacteria. This doesn't mean that there is any actual biological mechanism behind this pattern, though.